# How to set unnamed SQL parameters in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

If I add unnamed parameters to my `SqlCommand`, how do I set the parameter values, on the SqlCommand?

I have no problems when I use named parameters, where I can just do `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue()`.

Example:

```
Select * from sometable where SomeValue=? and AnotherValue=?
```

Comment: Ugh, that is unfortunate. I guess I'll have to name them, then. You should make an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ADO.NET against SQL Server, you cannot use those `?` for parameters - you always have to use `@paramName` approach.

The `?` for unnamed parameters is an ODBC "left-over" but not supported in ADO.NET when using SQL Server (not sure about MS-Access)

Answer (score 0):

Use ADODBConnection and ADODBCommand instead of SQL versions.